# swift open website with a webview

Tags: swift

My first app with swift... failing terribly.

I'm trying to open a website using webview and found this code online.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.sourcefreeze.com")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Well I get a fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Why should this value be null ?!

Answer (score 1):

One of two things may be going on.

1. Your webView is not hooked up to a storyboard element.
2. Your URL object isn't be initialized

I think it's the former, but I've taken the liberty of making your code safer by optionally binding your NSURL object.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.sourcefreeze.com") {
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
            webView.loadRequest(request)
        }
}
```

Comment: Is your webView hooked up in the interface builder?

Answer (score 0):

Change `webView.loadRequest(request)` to `webView?.loadRequest(request)`.

You need to unblock Transport Security which doesn't allow http loads. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33712228/5654848).

Comment: Check the updated answer. And as the other answer says, I don't think you've hooked up the @IBOutlet property in your storyboard.